# Converting string to a list of floats

Tags: python, list

In python, I currently have the following:

```
s = '(num1, num2)'
```

I am wondering how I could convert this to a list with float values so that the format is as follows:

```
s = [ num1, num2 ]
```

What are possible ways to do this, preferably without having to import anything. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

s = '(1e19, -23.430)'
```

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
(1e+19, -23.43)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
in_string = '(100, 200)'.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
out = list(map(float, in_string.split(',')))
```

Take initial string input and use .replace to replace ( and ) with nothing. Then, make an output list consisting of a map that makes each element of input.split(',') (which is a list of elements separated by comma) and converts it to float.

Comment: @Corralien it is just an example, I wanted to highlight the fact that it was the input. Just changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try  the built-in-function in python `eval()`:

```
eval('(1e19, -23.430)')
```

or use `regex`:

```
import re
s_in =  '(1e19, -23.430)'
s_out = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r"\d+[e]\d+|[-+]\d+\.\d+|\d+", s_in)]
print(s_out)
```

output:

```
[1e+19, -23.43]
```